# NSStatusBar loses state

Tags: swift, nsstatusbar

Some time ago I wrote an app using `NSStatusBar` to put a menu in the status bar. This had ever been working nicely. I did not use it for 2 or 3 years (so I guess in Yosemite it worked well). Now, when I run it in High Sierra it does lose state information. That is a menu which had been checked does not appear checked on the next time the menu is opened. Anyone got a clue whether something has changed in that area?

P.S. I thought that upgrading to Swift 4.something and targeting 10.13 rather than 10.9 would have fixed the issue, but nope. Today I got the same issue.

P.P.S: After further debugging it appears that the application does not seem to run permanently (now). After half an hour or so it eventually starts from scratch so the context which formerly was safe in my menu is gone. I'm just preparing to save the context in the preferences but a confirmation would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post a sample project that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Sorry, but I only have the full code and that basically does not differ from what all examples looked like and which had worked not too long ago,

Comment: Can you reduce your code down to a minimal project that reproduces the issue? If you do, we can try to figure out what's going on, but otherwise it's unlikely that there will be sufficient information to determine your problem.

Comment: Well, I just want to know if Apple did change something in that area I'm not aware of. If it's a coding issue I'll have to dig into it myself.

Comment: I had a similar issue not too long ago, with a bit of troubleshooting I found that the issue was only repeatable on my mac. Apparently an application called [bitbar](https://getbitbar.com/) was causing it. Try running the program on a fresh install or from a time machine backup of the same macOS build.

Comment: @RLoniello That would be a bit much pain ;-) I have access to another machine running High Sierra where I'll give it a try. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I ended up saving the state in the preferences which wasn't that complicated in the end. Well...